# How to trace blank cells of a Excel row in Java

Tags: java, excel

I am fetching data from an Excel file and storing them in an arraylist. All the cells are read properly except the blank cells. I want to keep track of the blank cells.

For example I have an Excel file with 7 columns amd among these 7 columns 5 are filled with data and 2 cells are empty, so after storing them in arraylist I am getting the list size as 12 instead of 14.

I assume that during iteration it is only considering the cells filled with data and ignoring the blank cells.

Here is my code

```
  ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList(); 
    int rownum=0;
    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\emsAttendancesheet_26-Nov-2013.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet=hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator=hssfSheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
            Row row=rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.iterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
                Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                 System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                 arrayList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());  
                }
                else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                    arrayList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Size of List::"+arrayList.size());
     }catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println("Exception in Exel   creation"+ex.getMessage());            
    }
```

My Exel file look like this:

```
Date         EmpId  EmpName Status In-Time  Out-Time  Comment

14-Nov-2013   112    Akas   Absent                    illness
```

Here In-Time and Out-time are blank, so it is not reading the empty cells. I require the empty cells to be considered. Can anyone suggest code?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604749/how-deal-with-blank-cells-in-excel-files-java ??

Answer (score 0):

To check the NULL or blank cells :

```
       for( int cellCounter = 0 ; cellCounter < maxNumOfCells ; cellCounter ++)
         { 
            HSSFCell cell;

            if( row.getCell(cellCounter ) == null ){
                cell = row.createCell(cellCounter);
            } else {
                cell = row.getCell(cellCounter);
            }
         }
```

Looping through the cells. From cell 0 to the last cell number. If the cell was found null, it would create the cell with a blank value. After that add your cell to list and then traverse through list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellItrator = row.iterator();
            if(row.getRowNum()==0){
                System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
                while(cellItrator.hasNext()){
                    Cell  cell = cellItrator.next();
                    System.out.println("CM Comumns "+ cell.toString());
                    tempList.add(cell.toString());

                    }
                }
            if(row.getRowNum()==1){
                Cell  cell = cellItrator.next();
                for(int i=0;i<tempList.size();i++){
                    int temStr= (int) Math.round(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println("Cell Value  " + temStr);
                        if (temStr==0) {   
                            System.out.println("Null Cell");
                            cell = cellItrator.next();
                        }
                        else {
                                System.out.println("Add Comumns "+cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                cell = cellItrator.next();
                                System.out.println(cell);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

}